# why I am not getting the not visible section header views in a tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

This is my viewController and as you can see when it loads up only three header views are visible.

[image]

why am I not getting the headerView textlabel text for those headers located below the initial view. I got 6 sections in total which corresponds to 6 headers views in total.

This is my code:

```
    //
//  FillinTheBlanksTableViewController.swift
//  GetJobbed
//
//  Created by Rustam Allakov on 9/22/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Rustam Allakov. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FillinTheBlanksTableViewController: UITableViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()



   }


   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)


      //
      //      print("the first section name is: ")
      //      println(tableView.headerViewForSection(0)!.textLabel.text!)

      let headerNames = getSectionNames()

      println(headerNames)

      print("the number of sections in a tableview ")
      println(tableView.numberOfSections())
   }

   //get all the sections you got
   func getVisibleSectionNames () -> [String] {

      var headerNames = [String]()
      if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows() as? [NSIndexPath] {

         headerNames = indexPaths.map { [unowned self] indexPath -> String in
            let section = indexPath.section
            if let headerText = self.tableView.headerViewForSection(section) {
               return headerText.textLabel.text!

            } else {
               return ""
            }
         }
      }

      return headerNames

   }
   ///array of strings with names of the headerViews in a tableview
   //why I am not getting the not visible part of my table view?
   func getSectionNames() -> [String] {
      var sectionNames = [String]()
      //how many section do my table view got ?
      for i in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections() {
//         if let headerView = tableView.headerViewForSection(i) {
//            println("the header number \(i)")
//            sectionNames.append(headerView.textLabel.text!)
//         } else {
//            println("i am not getting these \(i)")
//            
//         }

         let headerView = tableView.headerViewForSection(i)
         sectionNames.append(headerView?.textLabel.text ?? "not retreived header")

      }

      return sectionNames

   }





}
```

the print to the console:

> HEADER INFORMATION
>   EDUCATION
>   WORK EXPERIENCE
>   not retreived header
>   not retrieved header
>   not retreived header

I can only retrieve 3 of the 6 section header titles. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

An off-screen header view won't exist, so `headerViewForSection` will return nil for that section.

From the `UITableView` class [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/):

> **Return Value**
>
> The header view associated with the section, or nil if the section does not have a header view.

If you scroll your `tableView`, you'll see that the `tableView` creates header views as they appear on-screen, and deallocates them once they scroll off-screen.

*You can determine this by logging the address of the view that is returned to you.  The sections that have scrolled off-screen now return nil, while the ones that have now scrolled on-screen now return a view.*

*If you scroll a section header off-screen, then back on screen, the tableView actually returns a different view for that section, since the original one was deallocated, and a new one was created.*

**If you need the titles for off-screen headers, you will have to retrieve them from your model (or dataSource), as no headers will exist for those sections.**

You may want to consider implementing `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` to avoid having to access a headerView's textLabel to get the title.

Comment: cool... i got the idea... I will make the model like an array and distribute to each header in my table view. by that I will always have all the headers. very good idea...thanks a lot....